# How can I get opened URL in browser-action panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating a browser-action button on the right side of toolbar so that I can show deals on my extension depending upon the opened URL in tab.

Upon going through SDK documentation I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_toggle#Attaching_panels_to_buttons but it says that it's supported only for Firefox 30 onwards which is an issue.

To achieve this thing, I used browser-action lib by Rob-W (source: https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib)

Here is how it works:
Let's say, I have opened www.example.com, and it has 20 deals on my server. If I click on my browser-action button, it would open a panel showing deals depending upon the opened URL (with the help of an AJAX request)

Now the problem is:
The browser-action button (upon click) opens popup.html, and in my popup.html I have included popup.js. This is the file where I want access to the opened tab URL, so that I can perform the AJAX request. I do not get how can I pass the opened tab URL from main.js to popup.js.

Answer (score 0):

sdk/tabs give you the access to current tab and from there you can get the location.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs

Comment: with above library, i don't have access to it.

Comment: It becomes difficult to help when you don't have any code in jsfiddle that you worked with. 
https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/blob/master/lib/browserAction.js line 225, he actually used the same sdk library I was pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not get how can I pass the opened tab URL from main.js to
>   popup.js.

Have you tried to use the [port system.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port)

to emit a message from a content script:

```
self.port.emit("myContentScriptMessage", myContentScriptMessagePayload);
```

To receive a message from the add-on code:

```
self.port.on("myAddonMessage", function(myAddonMessagePayload) {
  // Handle the message
});
```

You can also use [widget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget) instead of the new UI module if you really want to target browsers before version 30, however it is depreciated and will probably be removed within the next few releases.